# How do I dismiss a progressView when it's fully loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a progress view that tracks the status of a Youtube video loading via WKWebView. When it's loaded, I want to dismiss the progressView because when I click back onto the main page of my app, the status bar is still there (but it doesn't display anything and takes up space, blocking other elements of my app). How do I, when the progressView is completely loaded, dismiss the progressView?

This is my class that deals with the WKWebView.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class VideoPlayViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    var progressView: UIProgressView!
    var videoURL: String = ""


    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: videoURL)!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

        //Progress View/ Refresh Button
        progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
        progressView.sizeToFit()
        let progressButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: progressView)
        progressView.progressTintColor = UIColor(red: 254, green: 53, blue: 98)

        let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
         refresh.tintColor = UIColor(red: 254, green: 53, blue: 98)

        toolbarItems = [progressButton, spacer, refresh]
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false

        // Lets the progress bar change according to what the Observer sends back (# from 0-1)
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)


    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {
            progressView.progress = Float(webView.estimatedProgress)
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more info / more code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    guard let keyPath = keyPath else { return }

    switch keyPath {  
    case "estimatedProgress":
        // If you are using a `UIProgressView`, this is how you update the progress
        progressView.isHidden = webView.estimatedProgress == 1
        progressView.progress = Float(webView.estimatedProgress)

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

and don't forgot to deinitialize the observers

```
 deinit {
    //remove all observers
    webView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress")
}
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AYA9mst - this is a link for images of the app. What I'm trying to do is dismiss the footer view or whatever it is that displays the progress view. what your solution does is just delete the progress bar itself, but not the whole footer bar view thing. (although I appreciate the code). any idea on how to fix it now?

Answer (score 0):

Check [webView(_:didFinish:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview) method of `WKNavigationDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

> You have to set typeable:

```
public typealias isCompletion = (_ isCompleted: Bool?) -> Void
```

> And add variables like this in class:

```
var completion: isCompletion?
```

> Now you have to create a method :

```
func webViewLoad(_ iscompleted:@escaping isCompletion){
    completion = iscompleted
    let url = URL(string: videoURL)!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
}
```

> You have to set completion in the delegate method

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("finish to load")
    completion(true)
}
```

> You can call this method from viewdidload like this:

```
    // show loading from here
    webViewLoad { (flag) in

    //hide loading here

    }
```